# If you write a file to the index in a merge that was conflicted, how do you go back to the conflicted state?

Tags: git, git-merge

Let's say I have a merge in git that result in a conflict on file `foo.txt`. Let's say I try to resolve that conflict with `foo.txt` and I `git add` that attempt. Then I realize I want to undo that attempt. How do I go back as if I never touched the file in the conflicted state?

To put it another way, *how do I get reset to a conflicted state?*

Answer (score 5):

```bash
git checkout -m foo.txt  # get the file back to its conflicted state
```

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation.

Comment: I think you don't need the reset. Just the checkout -m does it.